# Javascript open.window returns null in called function

Tags: javascript, function, class, dom-events

I have developed a function that when called should open a window but it returns `null`. If I do the opening window in the original JavaScript function it works. I suppose its the original function passing control to the other function but for some reason this doesn't work.

Here is my original function, this basically calls a new JavaScript file and loads an HTML file and when "Ready" it needs to display the window.open with the HTML file which is now in the form of string.

```
order.prototype.printMe = function() {
    order_resume.loadthis("myTestPage.html", "showData");

    // OPENING WINDOW HERE WORKS; but the the html file that is loaded
    // in above line hasn't finsihed loading - so i need to show it form
    // the function below once in "ready" state 

/*      child1 = window.open ("about:blank","_blank");
        child1.document.write( myDocument );
        child1.document.close();
*/      
}
```

And here's is my function that is called from original function:

```
function showResume() {
    this.req = false;

    reservaResumen.prototype.showData = function() {
        if (this.req.readyState == 4) {
            child1 = window.open("about:blank", "_blank"); /// THIS RETURNS NULL
            child1.document.write("test");
            child1.document.close();
        }
    }

    reservaResumen.prototype.loadthis = function(url, myMethod) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest && !(window.ActiveXObject)) {
            try {
                this.req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e) {
                this.req = false;
            }
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                this.req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    this.req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    this.req = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.req) {
            var loader = this;
            this.req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                eval("loader." + myMethod + ".call(loader)")
            }
            this.req.open("GET", url, true);
            this.req.send("");
        }
    }​
```

Comment: Is there a pop up blocker enabled?

Comment: no - because it opens it in the original function..

Comment: please, double check the pop up blocker settings. Browsers won't open windows without user interaction. Also, when user does eg. a click action, but you wait to long (eg. by doing some asynchronous operations like Ajax requests), the browsers also block the windows and return null for window.open.

Comment: thjis is NOT the case, because it opens in the original function

Comment: ok after redoing my code, its exactly the same but is working.. thanks for the reponse..

Don't know what was happening! thaks again

Comment: Re flag (not having an answer to accept): either add your *own* answer and accept it (after the delay), or we can close it no-longer-relevant.

Comment: Ok i have done a new Close as not being relevant .. but i have to wait for for additional votes?

Answer (score 0):

See [this discussion thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/88b3165b-980a-49fe-b66b-c86e8289c30d) that attributes this issue to the 32 bit IE8 browser running on 64bit Windows 7.

I just ran into this a few days ago. My development machine started to behave differently, popup windows no longer work on many sites, including the one that I develop, and there is no fix in sight. I have to start IE as administrator, then it works. Disabling protected mode does not resolve this. The 64 bit browser does not have this issue.

Why in my case this just started a few weeks ago I cannot say. There was a security update on 9/16 that I suspect caused the change in behavior. This is very odd.